# "Component Library" link is missing

Tags: powerapp, power-platform

I want to create a component library to define the layout and menu for our power apps... now when i went to the Apps link i could not the "Component Library" link, as follow:-

[image]

while on Microsoft docs @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/component-library  they mentioned that we should find this link

[image: johnjohn123_1-1697408476652.png]

any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Microsoft changed that page quite a bit.

The Component Library can now be found clicking the options on the left hand-side panel.

```
"...More" -> "Discover all"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply it worked for me,, it is wired that they updated the UI but still using the old UI inside their documentations..